# How to access Riverpod StateNotifier state outside build without ConsumerWidget or HookWidget?

Tags: flutter, dart, riverpod

I have this class:

```
 class BeatCounter extends StateNotifier<int> {
 BeatCounter() : super(8);

 int get counter => state;

 void increment() {
   if (state < 16) {
     state++;
     print('State $state');
   } else
   return;
 }

  void decrement() {
   if (state > 1) {
     state--;
   } else
     return;
   }
 }

   final beatCounterProvider = StateNotifierProvider((ref) => BeatCounter());
```

And want to access the state inside a class that extends a StatefullWidget that I don't want (/know how to) change. So I can't use 'with' to extend 'ConsumerWidget' or 'HookWidget'.
How do I get the state in this class?

```
class ChordsTrack extends BaseWidget {
  ChordsTrack({Key key, @required this.sample}) : super(key: key);
  final SOUND_SAMPLE sample;

  @override
  _ChordsTrackState createState() => _ChordsTrackState();
} 

class _ChordsTrackState extends BaseState<ChordsTrack> {
  MultitrackChordBassBoxCreator multitrackBox = 
  MultitrackChordBassBoxCreator();

   List<bool> _data = List.generate(***BeatCounter().state***, (i) => false);

   @override
   void on<Signal>(Signal signal) {
    setState(() => _data = AudioEngine.trackdata[widget.sample]);
   }
 ...
 }
```

Newbie question, I know, but would really appreciate some help.

Answer (score 0):

I solved it this way.

```
class BeatCounter extends StateNotifier<int> {
  BeatCounter() : super(8);

  static int counter = 8; //*

  void increment() {
     if (state < 16) {
      state++;
      counter++; //*
      } else
        return;
   }

   void decrement() {
     if (state > 1) {
        state--;
        counter--;//*
       } else
       return;
   }
}
```

Is there a better option?

Answer (score 0):

Just use `context.read(beatCounterProvider)` in your `initState`.

```
class _ChordsTrackState extends BaseState<ChordsTrack> {
  MultitrackChordBassBoxCreator multitrackBox = 
  MultitrackChordBassBoxCreator();

   List<bool> _data;
   
   @override
   void initState(){
      super.initState();
      _data = List.generate(context.read(beatCounterProvider).state, (i) => false);
   }  

   @override
   void on<Signal>(Signal signal) {
    setState(() => _data = AudioEngine.trackdata[widget.sample]);
   }
 ...
 }
```